# Apache CXF: Forwarding an information from an interceptor to the actual webservice implementation

Tags: java, jax-ws, cxf

I'm running a JAX-WS web service which is based on Apache CXF 2.3.1 on a JBoss6 server.

My service offers a function `getWeight`. This function should return the values in different units (kilos, pounds) depending on an additional information within the SOAP header. For that purpose I have added my own interceptor:

```
public class MySoapHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor
{
    public MySoapHeaderInterceptor()
    {
        super(Phase.USER_PROTOCOL);
    }

    ...
}
```

The intercepting works fine and I can parse the additional element from the SOAP header and can set up a variable based on this element:

```
boolean poundsRequested = true;
```

Now my problem occurs. I don't know how to forward the variable `poundsRequested` to my actual WebService implementation `MyServiceImpl`. This class is calling another class `ValueReader` where I finally need the information from the SOAP header.

I've already tried to set up a global static variable `ValueReader.poundsRequested`. But such a solution is not thread safe. It might happen that the calls of two clients interfere, and can overwrite each others set up variable.

**To sum up**: I basically need a possibility to forward a variable from an Apache CXF Interceptor to the actual webservice implementation. Moreover the value of this variable needs to be unique for each request.

Comment: Waitaminute… You're passing true functional information in the header?

Answer (score 2):

In the interceptor, you can save the values that you need on the incoming message:

```
message.put("my.value", value);
```

Inside your implementation, you can do one of two things:

1) Have the standard JAXWS WebServiceContext injected via an @Resource thing and call

```
context.getMessageContext().get("my.value");
```

2) Since you are tied to CXF anyway, do:

```
PhaseInterceptorChain.getCurrentMessage().get("my.value");
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. Your post helped me very much! I have chosen option 1. Basically I have already read about that idea before. I just had some other problems within my implementation which made it difficult to apply that idea. Well, I finally restructured my implementation :)

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, the format in which the weights are requested should be a part of your payload - it does not make sense for it to be a header.

You may not need an interceptor for getting hold of this header, if you are using JAX-WS(recommended with CXF), you can get to this using [@WebParam](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/jws/WebParam.html) annotation with header attribute set to true.

Comment: Yeah, setting these information within the header might not be the best, but I am forced to follow this approach due to some other reasons. There are also some other information which are passed within the SOAP header, where I am faced with the same problem. I ommited them for the ease of my post.

I don't want to follow the @WebParam-Notation. This will change the signature of the function within the WSDL. The extra element within the header should just be optional.